# If you block an email sender in Outlook will it still automatically forward the emails to another address if you have email forwarding set up?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, outlook-web-access

If you block an email sender in Outlook will it still automatically forward the emails to another address if you have email forwarding set up?

Comment: Forward what emails? The emails FROM the blocked sender? Any emails? This would be pretty each to test too, so what research have you done and what have you tried? Please clarify your question using the EDIT button to add more helpful and explanatory information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If you block an email sender in Outlook will it still automatically forward the emails to another address if you have email forwarding set up?

I tried testing in my environment and below are the results I got for reference:

- If the email forwarding is setup from the server side by the Exchange administrator, see [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/recipients-in-exchange-online/manage-user-mailboxes/configure-email-forwarding), then **YES**, the mail will still be forwarded.
  [image]

The mailbox entered in the image above can still receive the mail although the sender is added into the block list by the original recipient.
[image]

- If the email forwarding is setup by the inbox rule, then **NO**, the mail won't be forwarded.
  [image]